# Does Raku have a similar function to Python's Struct?

Tags: raku

Unpacking binary data in Python:

```
import struct

bytesarray = "01234567".encode('utf-8')
# Return a new Struct object which writes and reads binary data according to the format string. 
s = struct.Struct('=BI3s')
s = s.unpack(bytesarray) # Output: (48, 875770417, b'567')
```

Does Raku have a similar function to Python's Struct? How can I unpack binary data according to a format string in Raku?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's the [experimental unpack](https://docs.raku.org/routine/unpack)

```
use experimental :pack;

my $bytearray = "01234567".encode('utf-8');

say $bytearray.unpack("A1 L H");
```

It's not exactly the same, though; this outputs "(0 875770417 35)". You can tweak your way through it a bit, maybe.

There's also an implementation of Perl's `pack` / `unpack` in [P5pack](https://modules.raku.org/dist/P5pack)

Comment: Thanks you. `say $bytearray.unpack("C1 L A*"); ` works as expetced.